How can I switch language at runtime in a MAUI app?
In MauiProgram.cs I have this function:
public static void SetAppLanguage(string appLanguagesCurrent)
{
    CultureInfo culture = new("en-US");
    if (appLanguagesCurrent == "English")
    {
        Commons.Language = "en";
    }
    else if (appLanguagesCurrent == "Română")
    {
        Commons.Language = "ro";
        culture = new("ro-RO");
    }

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}

called by
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()

The app starts by default in English. Everything works fine.
We then switch the language in some "Settings" page which writes to some "settings.json" file (the user's preferences).
In that file we set the language to something else, say, Romanian (ro-RO).
If we restart the app, the code reads from that json file, and everything is fine - the language is correctly set, we pull data from the server, etc. All's good.
I have then created on the login page a "session's language switch" - if the user does not want to change the preferences, but desires to use the app in some language FOR this session only.
Let's say again that the default language is English. Say the user click on the Romanian flag on that Login page. On that event, I execute this code:
private async Task SwitchLanguage(string language)
{
    //By default the language is set in the Settings page. However, we can switch it here for this session.
    CultureInfo switchToCulture;
    if (language == "EN")
    {
        Commons.Language = "en";
        Globals.AppSettings.Language = "English";
        switchToCulture = new("en-US");
    }
    else
    {
        Commons.Language = "ro";
        Globals.AppSettings.Language = "Română";
        switchToCulture = new("ro-RO");
    }

    MauiProgram.SetAppLanguage(Globals.AppSettings.Language);
    GlobalLocalizationResourceManager.SetCulture(switchToCulture);
}

Nevermind the line
GlobalLocalizationResourceManager.SetCulture(switchToCulture)

(it's meant to translate the strings in the app).
What's strange, however, is that although in this function, by calling MauiProgram.SetAppLanguage("Română"), we set among others the values of CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture, and they show as changed in the Watches window, when I navigate to some other page of the app, these values (DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture, as well as Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture) show again as English in the Watches window, even though we have changed them previously (in SwitchLanguage()), so further data parsing then fails.
So, long story short:

If I start the app in EN, it works.
If I start it in RO, it works.
If I switch language without restarting the app, it fails on
processing.

Note: executing the line
(Application.Current as App).MainPage = new AppShell() 

does NOT help.
I assume this is something to do with threading. What am I doing wrong?


How can I switch language at runtime in a MAUI app? If I switch language without restarting the app, it fails on
processing.

About Localization, there is an known issue on MAUI GitHub. You can see this: .Net MAUI Localization #5595. You can also report your situation on it and track on this issue.

If you are offering a global method, you ought to also offer a global EventHandler (say public event EventHandler LanguageChanged. That way any UI/UX element can update in reaction to the LanguageChanged. Here's a mock example where the language changes trigger the HELLO_WORLD text to be updated:
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiLangApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiLangApp"
    x:Name="mainPage"
    x:DataType="local:MainPage"
    BindingContext="{Reference mainPage}">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25">
            <!--<Label Text="{Binding HELLO_WORLD}" />-->
            <Label Text="{Binding [HELLO_WORLD]}" />
            <Button
                Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked"
                CommandParameter="en"
                Text="English" />
            <Button
                Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked"
                CommandParameter="fr"
                Text="French" />
            <Button
                Clicked="LanguageButton_Clicked"
                CommandParameter="ro"
                Text="Română" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

using MauiLangApp.Resources.Strings;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MauiLangApp;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public event EventHandler LanguageChanged;

    public  void SetAppLanguage(string language)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(language);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        LanguageChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // public string HELLO_WORLD => AppStrings.HELLO_WORLD;
    public string this[string key] => AppStrings.ResourceManager.GetString(key);

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // LanguageChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HELLO_WORLD));
        LanguageChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged("Item");
    }

    private void LanguageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        SetAppLanguage(btn.CommandParameter.ToString());
    }
}

[EDIT]
In the code above, I switch from binding to every string in the string resource to just one getter public string this[string key] => AppStrings.ResourceManager.GetString(key);. This allows all localizable strings to be accessible through that one getter. PropertyChanged("Item") causes all localized strings on the page to update.
